# Fullcalendar show free slots

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm working on an events/appointment scripts and using the fullcalendar plugin.

Is it possible to show in the fullcalendar the free events and make them clickable and hide the unavailable events.

So the visitor can click on a free slot. I didn't find a solution yet.

I have an image as example but cannot add it yet here because i need 10+ rep to post images.

Comment: Nothing is stopping you from linking to an image. Also, you should include a minimal, but complete code example of your problem in your question.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using views in fullCalendar.

check this --> http://fullcalendar.io/docs1/views/Available_Views/

use dayClick and eventClick to allow user to click a empty or on event and describe it.

Eg:

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {

    alert('Now you can add an event');        

}


eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

    alert('Event Title: ' + calEvent.title);        

}
```

Hope this will be  use full for you.